# Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent for project POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I executed this command

```
 mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile-Dexec.mainClass=trident.MyClass
```

and  got this error

```
[INFO] Error 
building POM (may not be this project's POM). 
Project ID:org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0 
Reason: Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent for project:    
org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0 for project org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0
```

Here Pom file

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
 /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
         <repositories>
             <repository> 
                   <id>clojars.org</id>
                   <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
             </repository>
             <repository>
                   <id>github-releases</id>
                   <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-
                    releases/</url>  
             </repository> 
          </repositories>
             <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <configuration> 
                             <source>1.6</source>
                             <target>1.6</target> 
                    </configuration>
             </plugin> 
  </project>
```

Comment: I dont see a version for oss-parent which is available in Maven Central. Please add you pom file.

Comment: i can't post more as i got this message "it looks like your post is mostly code"

Answer (score 3):

So I ran into a the same error today, although the project I got the error from is different:

`Reason: Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent`

I realize this post is 5 months old, but I'm posting the solution that worked for me in case others stumble on to the same Stack Overflow link.

So the problem is not with your org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0 Project or it's POM file. It's with the parent project, oss.sonatype.pom. In my case, a 403 was returned when my local oss.sonatype-.pom was created. These were the contents:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when Maven is trying to build your projects; org.clojure will request oss.sonatype POM & when it cannot read oss.sonatype.pom as a valid POM file; it will throw the error you're seeing:

> [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM). 
>   Project ID:<...>
>
> Reason: Cannot find parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent for project:

After a bit of reading up, it seems that recently these repositories made changes to their URLs (Moving from HTTP to HTTPS), so if a call was made by any other POM or build for oss.sonatype over HTTP, the 403 HTML file was returned.

So the quick workaround is to head over to Maven Central, & get the required version of the oss.sonatype.pom file from their repositories & replace your local version with it. Then your Maven build won't fail on 'parent not found'.

The fix would be to test your URLs to check which URL(s) are not valid anymore.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you use a similar method to resolve your problem?